# Airparrot 2.6.2 not running in macOS Sierra

Tags: appletv, macos, airplay

I have a late 2009 iMac '27 and as a result, I am unable to enjoy airplay to stream video to my Apple TV. When previously I have used El Capitan, I managed to bypass this by using AirParrot2, a nice piece of software that provided all the benefits of the airplay for older iMacs for only $12.

However, since upgrading to Sierra, the older version of Airparrot2 (2.3) stopped seeing my Apple TV and the newer version (2.6.2) which should be suitable for Sierra just wouldn't run (no icon in menu bar).

If anyone have experienced the same issues with Sierra I would much appreciate solutions / feedback.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an older version installed (1.5.3), just tried it under Sierra, connected to an ATV4, got this message on the ATV:

> This AirPlay connection requires iOS 7.1 or later, OS X 10.10 or > later, or iTunes 11.2 or later.

Then I tried AP 2.6.2, and it worked fine.